# Flask-Bootstrap, flask-wtf, adding class to submit button

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask-wtforms

I'm using a flask-wtf submit button as follows:

```
 {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit, button_map={'submit': 'primary'}) }}
```

I want to add a class to the submit button but I can not find anything about that,
I'm pretty new with this but this http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#templates did not helped me a lot.

Anything to recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's super-easy, usually, so unless Flask-Bootstrap does something odd you can just tell it what you want the class to be:

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit, class="something", button_map={'submit': 'primary'}) }}
```

Generally, anything you pass to the rendering function that isn't recognised will be added as a parameter to the html, so you can do things like:

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit, cats="mew") }}
```

And your resulting html field would be something like `<input cats="mew" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">`